# 'Out of memory: Killed process 1190 (mysqld)' on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I periodically get the following messages on my Ubuntu 16.04 server with 1GB RAM:

```
[4768052.693699] Out of memory: Killed process 1190 (mysqld) total-vm:2037464kBB
```

The command

```
ps -eo pmem,pcpu,rss,vsize,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10
```

shows that MySQL uses 31.1% of memory (it is not clear virtual or RAM):

```
4.9  3.7 49324 1240772 node server.js production
4.2  0.1 42536 565796 php-fpm: pool slogpost
3.9  0.2 39068 566092 php-fpm: pool slogpost
3.2  0.2 31960 559592 php-fpm: pool devnote
3.2  0.2 31868 559736 php-fpm: pool devnote
31.3  0.5 310552 1381224 /usr/sbin/mysqld
2.7  0.3 27548 270584 php-fpm: pool beauty
2.6  0.3 25960 269612 php-fpm: pool beauty
1.0  0.0 10400 171716 (squid-1) -YC -f /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

The command

```
free -m
```

displays that 461 of 1023 swap is used:

```
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            968         544          59          48         363         182
Swap:          1023         461         562
```

1) What is the common practice (or a solution) in this situation?

2) What diagnostics can I do? How to determine how much memory should I allocate to MySQL? And how to determine which database uses how much memory?

3) At what condition should I increase RAM or swap?

4) Is it a good idea to simply increase RAM to 2GB?

Comment: Aren't most of your questions pretty much up to your own? Its telling you that it tried to exceed 2GB and was killed. Only you know what you're doing with that machine and whenever that could/should happen or not. Depending on it increasing the available memory would be a good option.

Comment: @Seth Yes, the most but not all, at least 2 and 3 are probably not.

Comment: Try googling before asking your questions. Apparently, there is [quite a bunch of people](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/getting-regular-out-of-memory-kill-process-how-to-resolve-this-isse) who have been tackling this issue already. Hopefully, by investigating what they have done in this respect, one by one, you might get some clues from them.